# Iron-router: React to data change

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I was wondering if it was possible for iron-router to change the route when a collection is updated?

Currently I have in my template:

```
Template.presenter.rendered = ->
  params = Router.current().params

  presentation = Slideshows.find(params._id)

  observer = presentation.observeChanges
    changed: (id, fields) ->
      Router.go('presenter',
        _id: id
        currentSlide: fields.currentSlide
      )
```

But the problem I have right now is that since I placed the observer in the rendered callback of the template I get this occasional bug that when the route is changed it happens twice instead of once. So is there a better way for me to react to a data change in the `Slideshows` collection so that I can change the route?

Comment: What happens if you add `observer.stop();` right before the `Router.go`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to first move the observer right before I execute the command for the fields to be updated in mongo. I also used @David Weldon's suggestion of putting `observer.stop()` right before calling `Router.go()`. Everything now works for me.